# vim / vi / linux: properly indent html file

Tags: html, linux, vim, vi, indentation

how can I easily indent html files with linux or vi or vim.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If your vim knows it's an html file (`:se filetype=html`), you can use the default indentation method (`gg=G`). I would have a look at `:help =`, it's quite powerful

Comment: wow, i just discovered it, it saved my day, luv this one, i used it to clean my smarty templates that were heavy indented, scary and awfull

Answer (score 2):

Use an HTML tidy plugin.
Here is some help [for vim](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Cleanup_your_HTML)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [html tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) program to have your html file(s) indented. It could also potentially correct things and change more than just indentation, so it might do more than you ask for, but unless that is a problem you will end up with better html files as a result of running tidy.